# Link github to IBM watson

Tags: github, gitlab, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I want to run github project in IBM Watson Studio. Is there any way I can do it directly? Or I have to write the code from scratch in Jupyter notebook?

I have already linked github repository with IBM Watson Project for publishing code but I want to know if there is any way to import code?

There is an option to import a Gitlab file. Can anyone help in converting a github project to gitlab project too?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

If you want to import your notebook from Github, You can follow steps to create a notebook and provide GitHub URL to import it into Watson Studio.

See instructions provided here: https://github.com/mamoonraja/analyze-call-center-calls-with-watson#watson-studio (You can skip step 3 if you don't need spark).

Comment: I want to import the entire repository, not just one notebook